# Understanding Strength and Correlation in Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

In the original paper of [Random Forest](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010933404324), the author introduces a concept of strength and correlation. In the appendix section, a step by step guide to calculating these values are given for the bootstrapping case. I have few doubts in this section.

1. What does $sd(\theta)$ signify? (equation A2).
2. As suggested by this [paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1788225), how the variance of margin is the correlation of two trees? From RF paper the equation of correlation is given by

$$\bar{\rho} = \frac{var(margin)}{(E_{\theta}(sd(\theta)))^2}$$

where $\theta$ is a tree in a random forest.